# Making a new array after destructuring items and destructuring behavior

Tags: angular, typescript

I am returning an observable from a service and I want to create a new array;

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t1zpt1?file=src/app/items-service.service.ts) code here

`allCodesAndIds: Option[] = [];`

service call

```
  getAllItems(): Observable<Item> {
    return of(this.jsonData);
  }
```

destructuring items the following way

```
  getAllItems() {
    const items$ = this.service.getAllItems();
    items$.pipe().subscribe(res => {
      const [id, code] = res.items;
      console.log(id, code);
    });
  }
```

I want my `allCodesAndIds` array to look like the following

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    descp: "item 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    descp: "item 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    descp: "item 3"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    descp: "item 4"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    descp: "item 5"
  }
]
```

Also, the current console.log only prints 2 items

```
{id: 1, descp: "item 1", code: "code1"}
{id: 2, descp: "item 2", code: "code2"}
```

whereas I was expecting it to return all 5 items. Could someone please explain the reason behind this. Please.

Thank you for your time and help !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to destructure your items like this:

```
const items = res.items.map(({id, descp}) => ({id, descp});
```

This is called `object destructuring`.

In your snippet, you are not using object destructuring but `array destructuring`. This takes the first and second item from your list of items.

```
const [item1, item2] = res.items;
```

Array destructuring has its use cases, too, e.g. separating head and tail of a list, useful for recursive algorithms:

```
const [first, ...rest] = res.items;
```